# How to validate points to generate a circle equation

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, equation

I want to know how to validate three points in a way that I could know if those points are correct to generate a circle. I'd like to know what the exceptions are so I can proceed to generate the circle equation.

For example, one exception is that you can't have three points in a straight line.
P1(34,15)
P2(67,15)
P3(27,15)

As you can see they have the same value on 'Y', so you can't find the circle equation for those three points, there would be an error.

What other exceptions should I consider?

Comment: Three points are needed to define a circle. If the points are not on a straight line then they will always form a circle. You can find the centre by taking the perpendicular bisectors of the line joining P1 to P2, and the line joining P2 to P3. The centre will be where the two bisectors intersect. One way to think about this is to consider a circle which touches two of the points and grow it until it hits the third point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points cannot define circle if they are on the straight line, so you can check whether cross product of two vectors is zero

```
if CrossProduct(P2-P1, P3-P1) <> 0 then
  OK, circle is possible

in coordinates:
(P2.X - P1.X) * (P3.Y - P1.Y) - (P3.X - P1.X) * (P2.Y - P1.Y)
```

Note that coincidence of points also gives zero result, so you may separate these cases (it is possible to build infinite number of circles through two or single point)

Comment: Thanks. :) . I completely forgot about the cross product, but is that the only exception that I should consider? I mean, only points in a straight line? I'm not sure if I'm explaining my point good enough.

Comment: Yes. At ht same line - no circle, coincident points - indefinite number of circles. There is theorem/corollary, but I don't know its English formulation - through three different points that don't belong to the same line, one can build a circle.